# Only update a particular row in a table angular 4?

Tags: angular

I have the following table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Url</th>
      <th>Registration Status</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let url of urls">
      <td><a href="http://www.{{url.Url}}" target="_blank">{{url.Url}}</a></td>
      <td>{{url.StatusText}}</td>
      <td><input type="button"  *ngIf="url.Status < 3" class="btn btn-primary" [value]="url.Step" (click)="Register(url.Id,url.Url,url.Status)"/><span *ngIf="updateInProgress">Running...</span></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeUrl(url)">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When the user clicks on a button on a particular row, I went to show a progress spinner next to it. The problem I am having is if I add a progress spinner place holder and set it to something, it will show for every row.
Also, is it possible after an operation is complete, I can just update part of the table.  Currently I am retrieving data from the server again, but I feel this is overkill. For example, if I update row 3 and I now want to set the status to complete on row 3, can I access the current value for the status at row 3 and just update that instead of going to the server and getting the updated data?

Comment: Where is your `progress spinner` html code?

Comment: @MohammadDayyan - I put the following: `<span *ngIf="updateInProgress">Running...</span>`, but when I set the `updateInProgress to true`, it shows `Running...` for every row not just the row that is actually updating.  I understand why, because that property is on every row, so I am curious how I can only show `Running...` for the row that was clicked on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like the following:

```
<tr *ngFor="let url of urls">
  <td><a href="http://www.{{url.Url}}" target="_blank">{{url.Url}}</a></td>
  <td>{{url.StatusText}}</td>
  <td><input type="button"  *ngIf="url.Status < 3" class="btn btn-primary" [value]="url.Step" (click)="Register(url.Id,url.Url,url.Status)"/><span *ngIf="url.updateInProgress">Running...</span></td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeUrl(url)">Remove</button></td>
</tr>
```

Notice to `*ngIf="url.updateInProgress"`

`Also, is it possible after an operation is complete, I can just update part of the table.`
Of course, yes.

**P.S:**
You don't need work with index, just work with `url` in your `removeUrl` or `Register`.
e.g:

```
private removeUrl(url) {
  url.updateInProgress = true;
  ...

}
```

Comment: Mohammed, how can I set `urlUpdateInProgress` for just that one row?

Comment: I think  I got it...I just need to access the array of urls by index.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you have something similar to span with spinner class which shows your spinner. When the user clicks to the button, find the exact span with id selector and add `spinner` class to it.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Url</th>
      <th>Registration Status</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let url of urls">
      <td><a href="http://www.{{url.Url}}" target="_blank">{{url.Url}}</a></td>
      <td>{{url.StatusText}}</td>
      <td><span id="url_{{url.Id}}"> </span></td>
      <td><input type="button"  *ngIf="url.Status < 3" class="btn btn-primary" [value]="url.Step" (click)="Register(url.Id,url.Url,url.Status)"/></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeUrl(url)">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and typescript code would be like this:

```
Register(id,url,status){
      $('#'+id).addClass('spinner'); //the spinner will spin while the 
      this.someAPI.someOperation().subscribe(() => {
          //success
      },
      ()=> {
         //error
      },
      () => {
        //complete
         $('#'+id).removeClass('spinner');
      });
}
```

Note that: it is not adviced direct DOM manipulation like I did now. You might want to use `ElementRef`.